# scratch upper image and make some area visible for lower image, crop that visible area of lower image ios

Tags: ios, image-processing

I am trying to do something like mask some area of interest with touch. So i used two imageViews. One is upper and second is lower. I need to scratch upper image and for scratched part lower image will clear to see. And now i want to mask that area and need to apply effect on that portion.

How can be this done?? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are probably looking for https://github.com/moqod/iOS-Scratch-n-See. Works great for scratch card effect.

Answer (score 0):

For scratching the image you can apply the pan gesture on your second imageview and when you move your finger over it you have to set the alpha of the touched pixel to zero so that you can view the first imageview and then after that you have to mask the area you have scratched for cropping.

Comment: and the problem is how to mask that area?